# Как в Laravel получить польхователя при использовании вебсокета?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, ratchet

Как в Laravel получить польхователя при использовании вебсокета?
Я использую Ratchet. Как понять залогинен ли пользователь и что єто за пользователь? `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` тут не работает

Comment: задача в том, чтобы на фронте понять какой пользователь и получать ему сокет или нет?

Comment: наоборот должно быть, сервер должен понять кто подсоединился и отправлять ли ему. сервер не должен рассылать уведомления для любого пользователя любому кто подсоединился

Comment: откуда идет отправка сокетов? Из слушателя?